# Teradata learning resources

Tags: learning

I'm moving from SQL Server to Teradata, therefore could someone recommend any good (preferably online) resources about Teradata? I'm not looking for information about basics, but rather about new features and concepts that are in Teradata.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would spend sometime over at the [Teradata Developer Exchange](http://developer.teradata.com), [Teradata Questions](http://teradataquestions.com) (currently disabled), and the [Teradata Forum](http://teradataforum.com). There is a wealth of information to be gleaned from these sites.

There is an Express version of Teradata that can be downloaded from [here](http://www.teradata.com/teradata-express/). This will allow you the opportunity to experiment with Teradata on your own computer. The VMware edition will probably provide you the most flexibility from a DBA perspective. The Windows version is great for developers who want to improve their understanding of SQL with Teradata.

Of course there are also questions about Teradata on Stack Overflow using the `teradata` tag.

Comment: Great, I was loking for something like this. Do You have any info when will Teradata Questions be available?

Comment: I suspect that Teradata Questions didn't have sufficient traffic to justify it's continued support by Stack Exchange. I'd have to talk to the admin and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the online forums mentioned above I would like to mention the **ATR** (=A-Terrific-Resource") forum which has now been replaced by a section inside of **Teradata Connections**.

This forum is frequented by R&D, product managers, consultants...etc people from Teradata and customers. When you can't find an answer elsewhere this is a place to head to.

The disadvantage is that it is only available to the TD customers and employees (+some qualified contractors)